# How to gather results from communication groups

Tags: python, mpi4py

In the code below (adapted from https://www.hlrs.de/training/self-study-materials/mpi-course-material#c3958), I am trying to construct two communication groups, which each calculates a sum and is stored by the group's root, and then gather the sum from each communication group's root in process 0. The code throws the following error in the cluster (i.e. managed by slurm). How can I correct the code to gather the sums from each communication root?

```
[warn] Epoll ADD(4) on fd 38 failed.  Old events were 0; read change was 0 (none); write change was 1 (add): Bad file descriptor
```

```
from mpi4py import MPI
import numpy as np

sumA = np.empty((), dtype=np.intc)
sumB = np.empty((), dtype=np.intc)

ranges = np.empty((1,3), dtype=np.intc)

comm_world = MPI.COMM_WORLD
world_size = comm_world.Get_size()
my_world_rank = np.array(comm_world.Get_rank(), dtype=np.intc)

# This will make mycolor a boolean but the bool class is a subclass of int and behaves like int in numerical contexts (true=1, false=0).
mycolor = (my_world_rank > (world_size-1)//3)
# This definition of mycolor implies that the first color is 0

# instead of sub_comm = comm_world.Split(mycolor, 0)
#    ... the following code is used:

world_group = comm_world.Get_group()

if (mycolor == 0):
   # first rank of my range:
   ranges[0][0] = 0
   # last  rank of my range:
   ranges[0][1] = (world_size-1)//3
else:
   # first rank of my range:
   ranges[0][0] = (world_size-1)//3 + 1
   # last  rank of my range:
   ranges[0][1] = world_size-1
 
# stride of ranks:
ranges[0][2] = 1;

# print("PE world:{:3d}, color={:d} first={:d}, last={:d}, stride={:d}".format( 
#           my_world_rank, mycolor, ranges[0][0], ranges[0][1], ranges[0][2]))
  
sub_group = world_group.Range_incl(ranges)
sub_comm = comm_world.Create(sub_group)

sub_size = sub_comm.Get_size()
my_sub_rank = np.array(sub_comm.Get_rank(), dtype=np.intc)

# Compute sum of all ranks.
# sub_comm.Allreduce (my_world_rank, (sumA, 1, MPI.INT), op=MPI.SUM) 
# sub_comm.Allreduce (my_sub_rank,   (sumB, 1, MPI.INT), op=MPI.SUM) 
# print("PE world:{:3d}, color={:d} sub:{:3d}, SumA={:3d}, SumB={:3d} in sub_comm".format( 
#           my_world_rank, mycolor, my_sub_rank, sumA, sumB));

sub_comm.Reduce(my_world_rank,   (sumA, 1, MPI.INT), op=MPI.SUM, root=ranges[0][0])

if my_world_rank==0:
   num_procs=12
   result_array = np.empty(num_procs, dtype=np.double)
   comm_world.Gather((sumA,1,MPI.DOUBLE), (result_array,1,MPI.DOUBLE), root=0) # root=0 is default, could be omitted
   print(result_array)
```